# VS 2010 keyboard shortcut list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

Is there a way to get a list of all of the keyboard shortcuts that are currently set in VisualStudio?  This would be a lot easier than surfing through all of the commands in the options window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of one site that lists a good number of the short cut keys.  I'm sure there are others.

http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

If you want to check the current bindings, there are articles about explaining how to do that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247076(v=VS.100).aspx

Note:  This took me about 12 seconds to google...

Comment: Any way to determine which are 'custom'?  I'm migrating from 2010->2013 and want to just grab the 15-20 shortcuts (which I can't even remember which I set) that I made custom so that I could apply them in 2013 as well (or at least the ones I want now).

Comment: So found a way to find only mine.  Basically export your entire (probably keyboard only would have worked) VS settings, then look for the element <UserShortcuts> in the exported settings.xml file and it should list any customizations you've done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3/) - extension that integrates Powershell console to Visual Studio. To get a list of all shortcuts, you would type following command in PowerConsole:

```
PS> $dte.Commands | ? { $_.Bindings } | % { Write-host $_.LocalizedName ';' $_.Bindings }
```

The result is a list of command names and corresponding keyboard shortcuts (semicolon separated), that you could, for example, export to Excel, and if you want to print out

Answer (score -1):

Here is the "official" list from Microsoft of all the default bindings in 2010. Has C++, VB.NET, C# and F#

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f

Comment: I am only interested in 'current' bindings.